# Joining a Windows 7 PC to a Windows Server 2019 Essentials Domain Controller

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain-controller

Is it possible to join all of our Windows 7 PC's to our new Windows Server 2019 Essentials domain controller, with Active Directory.

The PC's are running Windows 7 Pro.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to this see explanation here:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b7b7b55e-9e1b-4984-bbb4-ae4423258b4f/windows-server-2019-standard-with-active-directory-windows-7-domain-join?forum=ws2019